# Why is UUID not part of the dist folder after I compile my Typescript app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependencies, node-modules, tsc

I have a simple Typescript app and I don't understand the dependency behavior. I installed `UUID` but when I run the app from the deployed context it said that the `UUID` module was not found.

Sure enough, if I run `npm run build` and look in the `.\dist` folder it only has the compiled `.js` files from my `.ts` files, and nothing for `UUID`.

I created a sandbox repo to show the full setup.

https://github.com/rupe120/typescript-dependency-test

This is for an AWS Docker based Lambda.

As a side note, I also noticed that when I had my `quicksight.ts` and `resourceGroup.ts` in a sub-folder of `.\src`, after the compile the `.\dist` content was flattened with the sub-folders removed, but the references in the compiled `index.js` still used the sub-folder path. This also caused the execution to fail, though I can get around that issue and I can't find a way around the `UUID` issue. I would still like to better understand the sub-folder issue as well.

If anyone can point me to the docs explaining what I am missing here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A typescript build generally is not going to transpile library dependencies into the built output, so the build still requires the packages in the node_modules folder to execute.

Comment: As for your other issue, I think you're using `rootDir` wrong.  Remove it from tsconfig.json.